# Parsing a response for iPhone using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, credentials

I'm trying to access a website using my login credentials through an iPhone app but the `NSLog` just shows the site with the login screen...I need the one AFTER the login screen.  My code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webportal.factorforms.com/Portal/Form_Login.aspx"]];

    [request setPostValue:[self.usernameField text] forKey:@"Login1$UserName"];
    [request setPostValue:[self.passwordField text] forKey:@"Login1$Password"];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Request failed: %@",[request error]);
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Submitted form successfully");
    NSLog(@"Response was:");
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
}
```

My response is just the log in screen....I thought I would be getting the javascript for my actual login.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure if my question is clear.  I'm expecting the resulting data to show the screen after I have logged in, but instead I'm getting my original url that houses the login/password fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your website after login has multiple redirections? You must parse it too. ASIHttp can do it. [Just opinion.]

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems when trying to communicate with .NET sites, and doing the following worked for me:

1. including a post value for the submit button itself, like

   [request setPostValue:@"Login" forKey:@"Login1$LoginButton"];
2. including a post value for the page's viewstate since I think this can be  validated in some setups:

   NSString *viewState =   @"/wEPDwUKMjE0MjI5NDA3Ng9kFgICBA9kFgYCAQ9kFgQCAQ88KwAKAQAPFgIeCFVzZXJOYW1lZWRkAgcPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZAIDDxYCHwFoZAIFDxYCHgNzcmMFFkxvZ2luRnJhbWUvRkFDVE9SLmFzcHhkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBRdMb2dpbjEkTG9naW5JbWFnZUJ1dHRvbitnh1yDOsbCwQpF6Ic5hi0OUJ4q";

   [request setPostValue:viewState       forKey:@"__VIEWSTATE"];
3. include a post value for the page's event validation, since I think this can be  validated in some setups:

   NSString *eventValidation  = @"/wEWBQL9m8PyDQKUvNa1DwL666vYDAKnz4ybCAKI7MDFB3FJcnRzxnTY+gW6x83FqZF+QS+6";

   [request setPostValue:eventValidation forKey:@"__EVENTVALIDATION";

From memory, I threw all three of these at the problem and my login then succeeded, but I should really  have spent the time figuring out if all three were required.